# Whats wrong with this formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel and coding newbie. Getting very frustrated with a very specifc formula which should be simple.Can anybody tell me what wrong with this formula

```
=IF(W12<50,"U",IF(W12<65, "P",IF(W12<80,"M",IF(W12<101,"D"))))
```

Its picking up a specific value at cell`W12` and supposed to generate a grade in a spreadsheet based on that formula

Should be easy but can't get it to work.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to get it to do? Does the formula generate error? Or does it not give you the desired output?

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong with it? What is it supposed to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: the formula itself is fine, maybe you have not enter the desired conditions you were expecting

Comment: What is the problem you have? This formula works for me.

Comment: This works under Excel 2007, *make sure* you have the cell formatted as number and not text!

Comment: The only thing I can say is the last `IF` (`IF(W12<101,"D")`) is missing a `FALSE` condition.  If there shouldn't be any condition, you can simply change from `IF(W12<101,"D")` to just `"D"`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use ";" instead of "," (At least in my version; German version of EXCEL 2006 and 2016).

Comment: what version of excel do you use ?

Comment: `,` and `;` depends on `List Separator` defined character in `Control Panel> Region> Customize format> Numbers(Tab)`. That is not depended your region or Excel version. Your answer is false.